# Term Document matrix or Document Term matrix which one is better?

Tags: r, text-processing, tm, tf-idf, frequency-distribution

I am working on counting the frequency of unique words in a text document in R 3.2.2. I have collapsed so many articles into one single text document now and framed into corpus using `tm` package.

```
desc<-paste(column_input, collapse=" ")
desrc <- VectorSource(desc)
decorp<-Corpus(desrc)
#dedtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(decorp)
#dedtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(decorp)
```

There are 12000 odd terms in that one text doc. To proceed forward with matrix operations, I am not quite sure which is better method. Term Document matrix or Document Term matrix  ?

I hope that depends upon context. Is it better to use Term Document matrix rather than Document Term matrix in case of fewer documents with more terms. I just wanted to understand the logic behind this. So, I hope there is no need for any reproducible example. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Bala

Comment: What is your end goal? Classification (binary? multiclass?), regression, topic modeling...? *"I just wanted to understand the logic behind this. So, I hope there is no need for any reproducible example."* Sorry, asking for a general tutorial or resource without asking any specific coding question is offtopic here and will get this question closed unless you rephrase it.